# Is there any way to remove "-- (171 x 55)" from every frame title?

Tags: emacs

I'm setting all of the frame names with `(set-frame-name)` followed by `(toggle-frame-maximized)` [root cause of the problem], and they all have a `-- (171 x 55)` after the name (which appears to change depending upon the frame size).  It is not affecting any of my functions calling the frames by their short names, but it diminishes my efforts to make the frames nice looking with special names.  I've tried setting the `frame-title-format` a few different ways, including `nil`, but that appears to have no affect -- the page from wiki isn't very helpful on this issue:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameTitle   I'm using Emacs Trunk built `--with-ns` a couple of weeks ago -- Version 24.3.50 (9.0).  The variables that are being displayed in the frame title are:  `(frame-height frame)` and `(frame-width frame)`.  Here is a nifty diagnostic function from:  http://blog.andy.glew.ca/2012_10_02_archive.html

```
(defun print-frame-info ()
 (interactive)
  (message "%s"
    (mapcar
      (lambda (frame) "print frame"
        (reduce 'concat
          (mapcar (lambda (s) (format "%s" s))
            (list
            "TITLE=" (frame-parameter frame 'title) "\n"
            "   NAME=" (frame-parameter frame 'name) "\n"
            "   explicit-name=" (frame-parameter frame 'explicit-name) "\n"
            "   display=" (frame-parameter frame 'display) "\n"
            "   frame-height X frame-width=" (frame-height frame) "x" (frame-width frame) "\n"
            "   frame-pixel-height X frame-pixel-width=" (frame-pixel-height frame) "x" (frame-pixel-width frame) "\n"
            "   visibility=" (frame-parameter frame 'visibility) "\n"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    (frame-list)
    )
  )
)
```

Any ideas, please, regarding how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/frames-tabgroup.png))</sub>

Comment: Did you try setting `frame-title-format` with `setq-default`?

Comment: I tracked down the root cause to `toggle-frame-maximized`, which is triggering the behavior of the frame title including the `frame-height` and `frame-width`.  I just tried a few variations of `(setq-default frame-title-format nil)` and with `frame-height` and `frame-width`, but I haven't yet figured out the correct way to write it.

Comment: I'm going to update the question to reflect the problem stemming from `toggle-frame-maximized`.

Comment: The bug report that I submitted to the Emacs team regarding this issue on August 1, 2013 has just been fixed in the Trunk -- bug #15005 is now closed -- `bug#15005: 24.3.50; toggle-frame-maximized -- frame-title "-- (frame-width x frame-height)"`  I built a new Emacs Trunk --with-ns this morning (August 2, 2013) and am pleased to confirm that the issue is indeed fixed.  The workaround in my answer is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**:  The bug report that I submitted to the Emacs team regarding this issue on August 1, 2013 has just been fixed in the Trunk -- bug #15005 is now closed -- `bug#15005: 24.3.50; toggle-frame-maximized -- frame-title "-- (frame-width x frame-height)"`  I built a new Emacs Trunk --with-ns this morning (August 2, 2013) and am pleased to confirm that the issue is indeed fixed.  The workaround in my answer is no longer needed.

---

Previous workaround that was used temporarily pending the above bug fix:

Here is a hacked up solution -- if anyone has a better solution, please let me know.  With the non-hacked solution, calling `toggle-frame-maximized` before calling `set-frame-name` resolves the initial problem -- however, the problem returns as soon as the frame is minimized and/or maximized again.  This hack fixes the problem, but it is still possible to see for a split second that the frame is being reset to its default state while the function is running.  I'm not sure when `toggle-frame-maximized` was introduced, but it exists in the developer build of the Trunk.  I filed a bug report with the Emacs team relating to the latest build of Emacs Trunk.

```
(defalias 'toggle-frame-maximized 'lawlist-toggle-frame-maximized)
(defvar lawlist-restore-frame-name nil)
(defun lawlist-toggle-frame-maximized ()
  "Hack by lawlist of `toggle-frame-maximized` from frame.el
  of Emacs Trunk version 24.3.50 (9.0)."
  (interactive)
  (setq lawlist-restore-frame-name (frame-parameter nil 'name))
  (set-frame-name nil)
  (if (memq (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen) '(fullscreen fullboth))
      (modify-frame-parameters nil
      `((maximized . ,(unless (eq (frame-parameter nil 'maximized) 'maximized) 'maximized))))
    (modify-frame-parameters nil
      `((fullscreen . ,(unless (eq (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen) 'maximized) 'maximized)))))
  (set-frame-name lawlist-restore-frame-name) )
```